# sap-cloud-sdk-logger Support for Correlation ID

Tags: logging, sap-cloud-sdk, x-correlation-id

Will the `sap-cloud-sdk-logger` from `@sap-cloud-sdk/util` output the incoming **correlation ID** to the logs?

If not, how can we pass the correlation ID ourselves to the logger?

I couldn't find a corresponding hint in the [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/js/features/logging).

Background: We're seeing log entries from our app in Kibana, seemingly written by this logger, that are not instrumented with a `correlation_id`.

Comment: Cross-link: Also asked in the cloud-sdk repo - https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/1580

Answer (score 1):

This functionality [isn't currently built](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/1580#issuecomment-1782610174) into the SDK logger.

The SAP Cloud SDK has received a [feature request](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk-js/issues/4209) to make it possible.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, Pierre F.
Feel free to share your feedback in the GH issue linked above.
Thank you!